# PDFBox: Loading an Image Into PDF From a JAR Resource

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Good afternoon. I have a JAR file to which I have attached some images as resources in a folder called logos. I am being told to do this due to security restrictions (we don't want the image files to be exposed in the same folder as the JAR). I first tried to load these images in as if they were a File object, but that obviously doesn't work. I am now trying to use an InputStream to load the image into the required PDImageXObject, but the images are not rendering into the PDF. Here is a snippet of the code which I am using:

```
String logoName = "aLogoName.png";
PDDocument document = new PDDocument(); 

// the variable "generator" is an object used for operations in generating the PDF
InputStream logoFileAsStream = generator.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + logoName);
PDStream logoStream = new PDStream(document, logoFileAsStream);
PDImageXObject logoImage = new PDImageXObject(logoStream, new PDResources());

PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(PDRectangle.A4.getHeight(), PDRectangle.A4.getWidth()));
document.addPage(page);
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
contentStream.drawImage(logoImage, 500, 100);
```

Note that I have verified that the resource is getting loaded in correctly, as using logoFileAsStream.available() returns a different value for various logos. After running this code, the image does not actually get drawn on the PDF, and upon opening it, the error message "An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem." appears. Could someone please help me figure what's wrong with that code snippet/a different solution to load my images in as a resource from the JAR? Thanks so much. Let me know if more details are needed/clarification.

Comment: That's not the way to create images. Use the static methods of PDImageXObject instead. And close contentStream when done.

Comment: I would love to use those static methods (as I do with my other projects), but they require a specific file path or a File object to be used, which I cannot do because the images I want to reference are inside of the JAR as a resource. Do you know of a way of using those methods given my restriction? Which specific static method of PDImageXObject are you referring to?

Comment: PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray() in combination with IOUtils.toByteArray(). Alternatively use LosslessFactory.createFromImage() in combination with ImageIO.read().

Comment: I was looking at an older version of the reference thinking that my version of PDFBox was older, so I didn't see that function. Thank you so much for your response, that did it!!  Is there a way that I can give you credit for the right solution for this problem??

Comment: glad to hear that. I just posted an answer, so click on the checkmark. The latest version is 2.0.21, that's the best currently :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This PDImageXObject constructor is for internal PDFBox use only. You can use

```
PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(document, IOUtils.toByteArray(logoFileAsStream), logoName /* optional, can be null */)
```

for maximum flexibility, or if you know it is always a PNG file

```
LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, ImageIO.read(logoFileAsStream))
```

don't forget to close logoFileAsStream and contentStream.