# how to get File from Multipart File so that PDImageXObject can be created?

Tags: java, grails, pdfbox

I am using apache pdfbox to create a pdf from an image. I get an image from form submission. I convert it to BufferedImage. I need to create PDImageXObject from this image. Is there a way to convert this file to File object so that PDImageXObject.createFromFileByContent method can be used?

```
 def f = request.getFile('file')

 InputStream inputStream = f.getInputStream()

 BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
 float width = bimg.getWidth();
 float height = bimg.getHeight();
```

[image]

I appreciate any insights.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDFBox: Loading an Image Into PDF From a JAR Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64125825/pdfbox-loading-an-image-into-pdf-from-a-jar-resource)  i.e. convert the stream to a byte array. No need to call ImageIO.read() to convert to BufferedImage. You need 2.0.21.

Comment: sorry that doesnt work. i am using a little bit older version so PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray method is not available.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on having a local file (instead of updating your PDFBox version which would be the best practice), here's some code:

```
Path tempPath = Files.createTempFile("pdfbox", null);
Files.copy(inputStream, tempPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

System.out.println(tempPath);

// do stuff with that file

// delete when done        
Files.delete(tempPath);
```

to convert the Path object to a File object, use `tempPath.toFile()`.