# Unable to Insert image from classpath into PDF using PDFBox

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classpath, pdfbox

I have a springBoot project and i am trying to insert an image into PDF using PDFBox library. The image is present in src/main/resources/image folder (myImage.jpg). The implementation code is as given below. While running the program i am getting an error that image is not found at specified path. What is the correct way to retrieve the image from classpath in this scenario.

```
public class PDFImageService {  
  
public void insertImage() throws IOException {  
              
    //Loading an existing document   
      File file = new File("/eclipse-workspace/blank.pdf");  
      PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);  
  
//Retrieving the page  
      PDPage page = doc.getPage(1);  
  
//Creating PDImageXObject object  
      PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("/image/myImage.jpg",doc);  
  
//creating the PDPageContentStream object  
      PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);  

//Drawing the image in the PDF document  
contents.drawImage(pdImage, 250, 300);  

      System.out.println("Image inserted Successfully.");  
  
//Closing the PDPageContentStream object  
contents.close();         
  
//Saving the document  
doc.save("/eclipse-workspace/blank.pdf");  
  
//Closing the document  
doc.close();  
}
```

}

It works fine if i give the fully specified image path as

```
PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\PDF\myImage.jpg",doc);
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64130024/1729265

Comment: I've never tried loading resources this way, I would have used `PDFImageService.class.getResourceAsStream("/image/myImage.jpg")` and then put this into a byte array and then use `PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray()`.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr: I tried with PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(document, byteArray, "myImage"); I am getting Image type myImage is not supported error. I also tried by passing third parameter as null but still getting the same error.

Comment: Then it was either empty (did you copy the stream properly, check for error result?) or it wasn't a valid image or you have resource filtering on.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr: It worked with IOUtils.toByteArray.  
                                                                                                                                               InputStream imageAsStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(/image/myImage.jpg);                                                                                                               
PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(document, IOUtils.toByteArray(imageAsStream), null). Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, it works by using

```
PDImageXObject img;
try (InputStream is = PDFImageService.class.getResourceAsStream("/image/myImage.jpg");
{
    // check whether InputStream is null omitted
    byte [] ba = IOUtils.toByteArray(imageAsStream);
    img = PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(document, ba, "myImage.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless eclipse-workspace folder is on / (root) the top file in the OS then it would be implicit and incorrectly stated, when you installed configured eclipse it usually asserts the user home folder to put workspace into. If it is on root / then i suggest you add a FileNotFoundException before the IOException.